# Why am I getting "The type is deprecated" as an error in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I am using eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64 for Selenium (the Selenium version is selenium-standalone-2.44.0 and selenium-java-2.44.0). I am getting the error `The type is deprecated`. I have JavaSE-1.8 installed on my system.

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium; 
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
public class FirstTestCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 5555, "chrome", "http://www.xxxxxxyxyxyx.com");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Selenium` Interface and `DefaultSelenium` Class both belong to Selenium 1 and are deprecated. Selenium has advanced to Selenium 2 (WebDriver) and for this reason these warning messages are displayed to encourage users to stop using old Selenium 1 code and start using Selenium 2 (WebDriver) code.

To add: This has got nothing to do with your IDE (Eclipse) or your Java version.

You will want to use the following classes as these are part of Selenium 2 (WebDriver). `WebDriver` is an interface used by various Selenium 2 `drivers`.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```

Then you have various drivers that you can use. `RemoteWebDriver` / `HtmlUnitDriver` / `FireFoxDriver` / `ChromeDriver` / `IEDriverServer` etc. You will want to `import` the driver in your Java class.

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium();
```

Becomes

```
WebDriver driver = new TheSpecificDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [selenium mirror on github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/dbb21c609e6507593960f88e37d406543fbe1a55/java/client/src/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.java)

You should migrate to using WebDriver.

Just enhancing my answer, you might find this tutorial helpful https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1):

> > ```
> >  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
> >  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
> >
> >  public class FirstTestCase {
> >      public static void main(String[] args) {
> >          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
> >          driver.navigate().to("http://seleniumsimplified.com");
> >          driver.close();    
> >  }
> > ```
>
> }